# Detecting how many strings are present in a given variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that when you input a table, for example 'Fish, Carrot, Beef, Fish' it detects how many times 'Fish' was inputted, in this case 2. But when I try to do this it returns 'None' instead of 2.

```
def word_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == 'Fish':
            count = count + 1
            return count
word_count(['Fish', 'Carrot', 'Beef', 'Fish'])
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm quite new to Python, thank you.

Comment: You're iterating over characters in the string right now. Call it with `word_count(['Fish', 'Carrot', 'Beef', 'Fish'])`, and only return count all the way in the end (outside the for loop)

Comment: collections.Counter do this job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost correct, except:

`x`, according to your logic should be a list of strings, so you should enclose it in `[]` when calling the function. Then you can iterate over it.

You should return from the function when you've got your answer, i.e. iterated over the list.

So the corrected version would look like

```
def word_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == 'Fish':
            count = count + 1
    return count
word_count(['Fish', 'Carrot', 'Beef', 'Fish'])
```

Comment: I have updated the question. If that was the case `[]`, function was supposed to throw to error, but instead it is returning `None`. That means, OP has entered wrong example in the question. Actually he was calling it right

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri agreed that it should've given a `TypeError`, but it might not be wise to change code. Try commenting

Comment: I actually don't get it. You're absolutely right, but if he called it like that, with a list, it would return 1 -- right after it encountered the first 'Fish' .

Answer (score 1):

**Issue with your code**: Your function is `return`ing value within the `if` statement. So, when there is no `Fish` in your `x` list, it will return `None` (*which is default value returned by a function in Python*). Try below code and it will work:

```
def word_count(x):
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == 'Fish':
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

**Suggestion**: You may simplify you function by using the `count()` function present with lists. For example:

```
>>> my_list = ['Fish', 'Carrot', 'Beef', 'Fish']
>>> my_list.count('Fish')
2
```